# Different validation conditions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Are the following two validation conditions in Rails equivalent? Or are they not?

```
if: :new_record?
on: :create
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you asking, have you noticed instances when they don't seem to be the same?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same thing. And do you mean are they equivalent practically speaking, or do they follow literally the same (or almost the same) code path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent. The `on: :create` is just a DSL version that is then ultimately transformed (in the background) to `if: :new_record`.

From the [rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5bb1d4d288d019e276335465d0389fd2f5246bfd/activemodel/lib/active_model/)

validates (cf. validations/validates.rb#L123) leads us to `validates_with` (cf. validations/with.rb#L92) that leads us to `validate`(cf. validations.rb#L162) where we can see the `on` becomes an `if`:

```
    if options.key?(:on)
      options = options.dup
      options[:if] = Array(options[:if])
      options[:if].unshift ->(o) {
        !(Array(options[:on]) & Array(o.validation_context)).empty?
      }
    end
```

this leads us to the [default_validation_context](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1335959135b908c284e4d7179e9d8c1261f0ee95/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L73) which is equivalent to the `if: :new_record?`

```
def default_validation_context
  new_record? ? :create : :update
end
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first answer ever here - if it's convoluted, let me know and I'll try to make it clearer. Also I couldn't add more than 2 links, but if you go to the linked rails source code, just navigate to the files I mentioned so you can find the code I mentioned.